# How to allocate bandwidth for specific process

Tags: nginx, debian, ftp

I have nginx php server with Debian OS on my production VPS , the problem is that nginx eats all of my bandwidth.

When I try to upload something using ftp, the connection times out most of the times.

Today I killed the nginx process and tried to upload something with ftp and it worked with stable speed and faster connecting .

So the problem is that the system doesn't allocate enough bandwidth for ftp server to work unless I terminate the nginx

Any idea how to fix / diagnosis the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a built in traffic shaper in linux kernel. You can implement it by tc directive.
In your case I'd reccomend this:

1) Create a root directive

```
# tc qdisc add dev eth0 handle ffff: ingress
```

2) Create a directive tree both both traffic classes (256k for http and 64k for ftp)

```
#tc filter add dev eth0 parent ffff: protocol ip prio 50 \
            u32 ip dport 80 0xffff \
            police rate 256kbit burst 10k drop flowid :1
# tc filter add dev eth0 parent ffff: protocol ip prio 50 \
            u32 ip dport 21 0xffff \
            police rate 64kbit burst 10k drop flowid :1
```

You can find very thorough explanation here http://lartc.org/howto/

Comment: Just didn't like the concrete numbers.. Can I set them relatively? Something like `80%/20%`

Comment: No, with `tc` you have to specify precise amounts.  It is unable to determine what the actual throughput is.  Even if an interface is detected as 1GbE it might only have an actual 100Mbit uplink.  You'll have to tell it exactly what to use.

Comment: well , if the whole bandwidth is 100 kb for example and port 80 got 256kb rule and on the other hand port 21 got 64kb.
port 80 will take them all or not ? @Gene